# How can I set a header or a footer in cordova-plugin-html2pdf?

Tags: html, pdf-generation, cordova-plugins

I want to create a PDF in a cordova application using the cordova-plugin-html2pdf. There are no bugs here, and the creation is okay, but I don't know how to put a header (or a footer) in every page of the generated PDF.

This is the code I have now for the creation of PDF:

```
var htmlDoc = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/main.css'></head><body>"+document.getElementById("myDocument").innerHTML+"</body></html>";

    window.html2pdf.create(htmlDoc,
            "test.pdf",
            function(){
                console.log("PDF Creation Success!");
            },
            function(){
                console.log("PDF Creation Fail!");
            }
        );
```

How can I add the header to the generated PDF?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @vishal_g nope, I did not